# AWS CloudFront phppBB3 user-agent header

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, phpbb3

I am experimenting setting up a site which includes phpBB3 to use AWS CloudFront. phpBB3 uses the user-agent header to detect robots and spiders so I have added a white list header to a CloudFront behaviour to forward the user-agent, this works but AWS warns against this because of the number of permutations of user-agent header.

So, is there a better way of achieving the detection of robots in phpBB3 when using cloud front?

Answer (score 1):

Possibly not. I'm assuming you want to verify that *every* request doesn't come from a bot / spider? If not, perhaps you could avoid header whitelisting for certain url patterns (assuming that phpBB3 wouldn't treat the Cloudfront UA as a bot / spider) and still gain some performance uplift.

Another option might be the Cloudfront specific headers that can be added to origin requests. Cloudfront does it's own UA detection, and providing you've added these headers to the Whitelist, they should be passed to the origin:

CloudFront-Is-Mobile-Viewer

CloudFront-Is-Tablet-Viewer

CloudFront-Is-Desktop-Viewer

I'm not sure what would be passed in the case of a bot / spider - you'd need to check that out / get clarification from Amazon, but if they were all false, then perhaps you could configure phpBB3 to return an error page, which would then be cached for UA that fall into that category.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I am investigation the CloudFront-Is-xxx headers, but I am reluctant to use them for bot detection in-case a non-bot gets served up the wrong content. I have asked AWS if there is defined behaviour for bots, but as yet no response. I think this is best solved on the phpBB side perhaps detecting Bots by IP address. I will ask on the phpBB forums.

Answer (score 0):

To mitigate the high number of requests sent to the origin due to 'User-Agent' whitelist, a workaround would be to set for example two 'User-Agent' values: one for real requests and the other for Bots/Spiders/Crawlers and to use a [**Lambda@Edge**](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/lambda-at-the-edge.html) function that checks the 'User-Agent' of the **Viewer Request**, and change it to one of the two values specified. 
Find below a sample function that can be used for this, it can be updated to match your needs:

```js
'use strict';

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    const headers = event.Records[0].cf.request.headers;
    
    if ((headers['User-Agent'] == 'Googlebot') || (headers['User-Agent'] == 'MSN' || (headers['User-Agent'] == 'AbachoBOT' || (headers['User-Agent'] == 'Gigabot' || (headers['User-Agent'] == 'ia_archiver' || (headers['User-Agent'] == 'Tarantula')) {
        headers['User-Agent'] = 'This is a Bot, Spider or Crawler - Do what you want :-)';
    }
    else {
        headers['User-Agent'] = 'Amazon CloudFront - Real Request - Do what you want :-)';
    }
    
    callback(null, event.Records[0].cf.request);
};
```